# Replacing any <> closed string with a $ sign at the beginning of the same string in a text file

Tags: text-processing

I have some files resides on a Linux system, containing some placeholders like this file one below:

test.txt:

```
This is a line with <VARIABLE1>@<VARIABLE2>.
This is a line with <VARIABLE3>.
This is a line with <VARIABLE_UNKNOWN>.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

I want to change this file showing like below:

```
This is a test line with $VARIABLE1@$VARIABLE2.
This is a test line with $VARIABLE3.
This is a test line with $VARIABLE_UNKNOWN.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

Notice, all these variables closed with `<>` contain only uppercase letters, digits and underscores.

I could have used the following method but `a<b` becomes `a$b`.

```
file_contents=$(<$file_path)
file_contents=${file_contents//</$}
file_contents=$(echo "$file_contents" | tr -d '>')
echo "$file_contents" > test.txt
```

I am trying to avoid a complex `sed` command which becomes very difficult to debug. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What should happen for a source string like "I've got three <VARIABLE1>s"? Your rule as defined would result in a variable placeholder `VARIABLE1` being replaced by the variable name `$variable1s`

Comment: You should have included in your sample input/output some examples like `<foo>` or `<###>` or `<>` that should not be replaced so we could properly test potential solutions. It's always much easier to match the strings you want that to not match similar strings you do not want.

Comment: If your input can contain `a<b` as you show, then it can almost certainly contain that followed by a target string `a<b <VAR>`, which would be a failure case for a typical regexp approach like `<[^>]+>`, and probably `a<b>` too.

Comment: Hi @EdMorton, I removed my previous comments seeing your solution down the page. Wanted to write there, but I see you commented again which was not visible to me before I deleted my commnet.

Comment: I agree to your point on the scenario of `<VARIABLE1>s`. In that case your solution to convert `<VARIABLE1>` to `"${VARIABLE1}"` should serve my purpose.

Comment: @EdMorton, the files had been there for long. The script was very complex due to handing the complex files. Now, debugging the existing complex script became a nightmare since fixing one issue develop another. So, I wrote the script to create temporary environment variables to update the script. `eval` was easy. Scenario doesn't have these variable names in the systems. What other adverse impact can I have using eval?

Comment: Its extremely unlikely that using `eval` is the best approach, it's probably a very bad/dangerous approach to whatever it is you really are trying to do. You may want [envsubst](https://linux.die.net/man/1/envsubst) instead. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048 for some more info on `eval`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is simple substitutions on individual lines, the sed command to do this wouldn't be complex:

```
$ sed -E 's/<([[:upper:][:digit:]_]+)>/$\1/g' file
This is a line with $VARIABLE1@$VARIABLE2.
This is a line with $VARIABLE3.
This is a line with $VARIABLE_UNKNOWN.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

or if your sed doesn't have `-E` then with any POSIX sed:

```
sed 's/<\([[:upper:][:digit:]_]\{1,\}\)>/$\1/g' file
```

If your sed isn't even POSIX compliant then **get a new one** but for this particular thing you could probably do:

```
sed 's/<\([A-Z0-9_][A-Z0-9_]*\)>/$\1/g' file
```

As [@chrisdavies points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758329/replacing-any-closed-string-with-a-sign-at-the-beginning-of-the-same-string/758356#comment1445097_758329), that's probably not the output you really should be trying to get, though, as it'll turn `<VAR1>27` into `$VAR127` and you should really be aiming for either of these instead:

```
$ sed -E 's/<([[:alnum:]_]+)>/${\1}/g' file
This is a line with ${VARIABLE1}@${VARIABLE2}.
This is a line with ${VARIABLE3}.
This is a line with ${VARIABLE_UNKNOWN}.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

```
$ sed -E 's/<([[:alnum:]_]+)>/"${\1}"/g' file
This is a line with "${VARIABLE1}"@"${VARIABLE2}".
This is a line with "${VARIABLE3}".
This is a line with "${VARIABLE_UNKNOWN}".
This is another line contains a<b.
```

depending on what you're planning to do with that output.

FWIW usually when people have placeholder strings in text they don't replace them with the **names** of shell variables, they replace them with the **contents** of shell variables because otherwise what was the point of using placeholders in the text when you could have just created it with the shell variables names in the first place?

Comment: Replacing `$VAR` with variable values can be done with `envsubst` for instance, so the OP may just be trying to convert those templates into an `envsubst`-ready one. But then I agree it would be just as easy to do `perl -pe 's/<([A-Z\d_]+)>/$ENV{$1}/g'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, thank you for your comment showing the perl syntax. As both `perl` and `sed` are using almost the same regex, I won't have any issue using `sed`.

Comment: @EdMorton, I do not have `-E`, how do I enclose them with `"{}"` like  `"${VARIABLE1}"` ?

Comment: `sed 's/<\([A-Z0-9_]*\)>/"${\1}"/g'` works, without escaping `"`, `$` or `{}`. Any concerns?

Comment: There's nothing special about `"{}"`, the `-E` was only to be able to use `+` and no backslashes before `(` and `)`. Without it you should use the script I mentioned in my answer after the text "if your sed doesn't have `-E` then". By using `*` instead of `+` or `\{1,\}` you'd convert `<>` to `$`.

Comment: Thank you, @EdMorton!

Answer (score 2):

If the problem can be stated as "I want to convert all strings enclosed in `< >` and consisting of only one or more upper case letters, digits and underscores enclosed in `< >` with themselves but with a `$` instead of `< >`", then you can do this:

```
$ perl -pe 's/<([A-Z\d_]+)>/\$$1/g' file 
This is a line with $VARIABLE1@$VARIABLE2.
This is a line with $VARIABLE3.
This is a line with $VARIABLE_UNKNOWN.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

The `-pe` means "read the input file line by line, apply the script given by `-e` and then print each line". We then use the substitution operator (`s/OLD/NEW/`) with the `g` flag so it replaces all occurrences on the line. Finally, the regex looks for `<` followed by one or more (the `+` means one or more) of capital ASCII letters (`A-Z`), ASCII¹ decimal digits (`\d`)  or underscores (`_`) ending with a `>`. Now, because the pattern is in parentheses  (`([A-Z\d_]+)`), we have "captured" it and can refer to it as `$1` in the replacement. So we replace what we matched with a `$` (which needs to be escaped as `\$`) and then whatever was matched: `\$$1`.

---

<sup>¹ at least as long as the `$PERL_UNICODE` environment variable is not set in which case it could match on other sorts of decimal digits. Use the `a` flag to the `s///` operator to guarantee  only 0123456789 are matched, or replace `\d` with `0-9` or `0123456789`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -pe 's:g/ \< ( <[A..Z0..9_]>+ ) \> /\$$0/;'  file
```

Once again, this is pretty much a direct translation of @terdon's excellent Perl answer.

In Raku,

1. Regex modifiers such as `g`lobal go at the head of the matcher preceded by a colon, to give the `s:g///` "substitute-global" form.
2. Within the recognition domain, a custom character class is created with `<[ ... ]>` enclosing square brackets surrounded by angle brackets. Square brackets alone are used to group regex atoms and/or properties together (see example at bottom).
3. A range of characters is specified with `..` double-dots as in (for example) `A..Z` or `0..9`.
4. Raku has simplified escaping rules such that all non-alphanumeric non-underscore characters must be either quoted or (backslash) escaped to be understood as literals within regexes, hence the need to use `\<` and `\>` in the recognition domain.
5. Numbered captures are specified in Raku by parentheses (same as in Perl), however these numbered captures start from `$0` and must be used in the replacement domain as such.
6. The OP refers to erroneous substitutions, and often the requirement to backslash certain characters can be problematic. To assist, Raku allows `{...}` codeblocks in the replacement domain, such that the above replacement can be written `{"\$$0"}` (i.e. an interpolated string). Very useful for performing simple math (sums, etc.) in the output.

Sample Input:

```
This is a line with <VARIABLE1>@<VARIABLE2>.
This is a line with <VARIABLE3>.
This is a line with <VARIABLE_UNKNOWN>.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

Sample Output:

```
This is a line with $VARIABLE1@$VARIABLE2.
This is a line with $VARIABLE3.
This is a line with $VARIABLE_UNKNOWN.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

Finally, @terdon gives an excellent overview of the problem with all regex systems such that there needs to be a precise understanding of what is meant by ***digit***, i.e. are these ASCII digits or Unicode digits?

Raku prides itself on being a "Unicode-ready" language, and you can find an extensive list of Unicode character classes for use in Raku regexes in the first link at the bottom. Hence in Raku the `\d` digit shorthand ***includes Unicode digits.*** You can enumerate digits `0..9` as above, or subset/restrict `\d` digits to ASCII digits using the `<:ASCII>` character class combined with an `&&` Conjunction, as in `[<:ASCII> && \d]`:

```
~$ raku -pe ' s:g/ \< ( [ [<:ASCII> && \d] | <:Lu> | _ ]+ ) \> /\$$0/;'  file
```

Above, `<:Lu>` is the Unicode character class for "Letters-uppercase". If so desired, the same `<:ASCII>` trick can be used to subset to "ASCII Letters-uppercase" (or more simply, rearrange the square brackets above to regroup).

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Unicode_properties
https://www.unicode.org/terminology/digits.html
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Conjunction:_&&
https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes
https://raku.org

Answer (score 0):

Using `gawk`:

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/<([[:alnum:]_]+)>/, "$\\1", "g")}' file
# Or

$ awk '{print gensub(/<(\w+)>/, "$\\1", "g")}' file
This is a line with $VARIABLE1@$VARIABLE2.
This is a line with $VARIABLE3.
This is a line with $VARIABLE_UNKNOWN.
This is another line contains a<b.
```

In gensub() function a subpattern can be memorized using parentheses as `captured group` and referred back to it later with a `backreference` as *`\n`*.

From `GNU awk` manual:

> *gensub()* provides an additional feature that is not available in *sub()* or *gsub()*: the ability to specify components of a regexp in the replacement text. This is done by using parentheses in the regexp to mark the components and then specifying *‘\N’* in the replacement text, where *N* is a digit from 1 to 9.

Comment: But does this answer restrict the substitution to only UPPERCASE letters? Or will lowercase letters enclosed within angle-brackets get substituted as well?